# Data not queried in cnosdb

Tags: cnosdb

1. Creating the database

```sql
create database test_db with replica 0;
```

2. Write data

```sql
telegraf --config telegraf.conf
```

This is telegraf's logs

```sql
2024-01-27T09:39:24Z I! Loading config: telegraf.conf
2024-01-27T09:39:24Z I! Starting Telegraf 1.29.2 brought to you by InfluxData the makers of InfluxDB
2024-01-27T09:39:24Z I! Available plugins: 241 inputs, 9 aggregators, 30 processors, 24 parsers, 60 outputs, 5 secret-stores
2024-01-27T09:39:24Z I! Loaded inputs: cpu disk diskio mem system
2024-01-27T09:39:24Z I! Loaded aggregators:
2024-01-27T09:39:24Z I! Loaded processors:
2024-01-27T09:39:24Z I! Loaded secretstores:
2024-01-27T09:39:24Z I! Loaded outputs: http
2024-01-27T09:39:24Z I! Tags enabled: host=IvandeMacBook-Pro.local
2024-01-27T09:39:24Z I! [agent] Config: Interval:10s, Quiet:false, Hostname:"IvandeMacBook-Pro.local", Flush Interval:10s
```

This is the telegraf configuration.

```sql
[[outputs.http]]
  url = "http://127.0.0.1:8902/api/v1/write?db=test_db"
  timeout = "5s"
  method = "POST"
  username = "root"
  password = ""
  data_format = "influx"
  use_batch_format = true
  content_encoding = "identity"
  idle_conn_timeout = 10
[[inputs.cpu]]
  percpu = true
  totalcpu = true
  collect_cpu_time = false
  report_active = false
  core_tags = false
[[inputs.disk]]
  ignore_fs = ["tmpfs", "devtmpfs", "devfs", "iso9660", "overlay", "aufs", "squashfs"]
[[inputs.diskio]]
[[inputs.mem]]
[[inputs.system]]
```

3. Querying data

```
use test_db;
show tables;
```

There's nothing.

If things go well, you should see the `cpu`, `disk`, `diskio` tables after `show tables`.